# ASP.NET MVC 4 Website Mobile Version

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an in house web application using ASP.NET MVC4 framework and i finished it. Now i want to support a mobile version for the web application such that when a user browse the website from a mobile device he switched ***automatically*** to the mobile version.

I am asking here about how to organize things like controllers and view models.
I want to use the same controller and select view based on the browser agent.

Also because the mobile pages not contains all the data like desktop version, the view model will be different. It will be nice if there is a ***generic way*** to pass a model to the view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC 4 supports [`Display Mode Providers`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features) which allow you to have specific views for the mobile user agents and share the same controllers and models. For example you could have the following views:

```
Index.cshtml
Index.Mobile.cshtml
Index.iPhone.cshtml
...
```

Based on the user agent and the device mode providers you have configured ASP.NET MVC will automatically pick the right view for you.

Comment: Darin, Thank you to show me that. This is good but the view models are different and i want a generic way to pass the right model to view. we can check the mode in the controller before creating the view model then we pass it. Also we can have the model that can hold information for the two modes(desktop & mobile) and each view can take what it need only from it. But the check in the controller is UGLY. Thanks